# Proof of existence of simple group of Order 168 in Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, simple-groups

So I want to show that GL(V) is a simple group, where V is a three-dimensional vector space over the field of 2 elements.  I am following Dummit and Foote (last paragraph on p.211) but there is one part I don't understand and it's driving me crazy.  GL(V) is acting on V.  Assume there exists a nontrivial, proper normal subgroup H of GL(V).  Let x be a point of V (i.e. a 1 dimensional subspace) and let N be the stabilizer of x in GL(V).  So I understand the N has index 7 in GL(V) and that H is not a subgroup of N, but how do these two things imply that HN = GL(V)?  The point is to show that 7 divides the order of H.  The only other thing I have seen on the internet is the claim that the latter follows from H being transitive.  I would be very grateful if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: I think you mean 168.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $H$ is normal, $HN$ is a subgroup containing $N$.

Since $N$ has prime index, there are only two possibilities: $HN=N$, or $HN=GL(V)$.

But if $HN=N$, then $H\leq HN \leq N$, so $H\leq N$.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Can you explain the second part.  Clearly there is something really obvious that I'm not seeing right now.

Comment: @Michael If $A\leq B\leq C$, there is a standard theorem (by counting cosets) that $|C:A| = |C:B| \cdot |B:A|$.  If $|C:A|$ is prime, then either $|C:B|=1$ or $|B:A|=1$.

Comment: Ah I see it now, thanks.